# Работа с изображениями в PYTHON 3 и tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, tkinter

Добрый день! Начала изучать **python** и **tkinter**.
Сформировался такой вопрос. При открытии файла пытаюсь передать значение пути файла в переменную, а потом файл с изображением нарисовать в канву.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Пробовала через `Canvas` и `Label`.

```
def open_file():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select your file", filetypes=(("jpeg files", "*jpg"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    name=root.filename
    # label = Label(f1, image=name)
    # label.pack()

    canvas = Canvas(f1, width=400, height=300)
    pilImage = Image.open(name)
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
    canvas.create_image(40,400,image=image1)
    canvas.pack()
```

Comment: Какие ошибки выдает хоть? Вот здесь http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm написано в конце, что при выходе из функции сборщик мусора вычистит картинку, если ее не присвоить куда-то еще.

Answer (score 2):

При выходе из функции локальный объект `image1` будет удален сборщиком мусора, поскольку Python не знает, что он используется внутри Tk. Чтобы этого не произошло, можно поступить следующим образом: объявить глобальный объект `imgs` и хранить все картинки в нем.

```
class Struct(object): pass
imgs = Struct()
```

А у себя в функции

```
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
canvas.create_image(40,400,image=image1)
```

замените на

```
global imgs
imgs.image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)
canvas.create_image(40,400,image=imgs.image1)
```

Важное дополнение: при повторном вызове функции значение `imgs.image1` будет перезаписано новым изображением, а старую картинку точно так же сотрет сборщик мусора. Если так и надо (загружаем по одной картинке - старая не нужна), то все в порядке. Для более общего случая подход следует усложнить.

Comment: Вместо глобальной переменной, можно внутри класса атрибут завести, например: [`self._photo_image`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8b05c3ea0302f0e2c14c)